# Converting diacritics to numerical HTML code with HTML Purifier

Tags: php, html-entities, htmlpurifier, diacritics

I'm having trouble finding the correct setting for `HTML Purifier 4.3.0` to convert diacritics to numerical HTML code. Is this possible using this library?

So, from `încă` to `&#238;nc&#259;&#160;`.

Comment: Why do you want to do that anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [demo](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php): by default: no. To me, but there isn't a clear description of what it does and doesn't, HTML Purifier looks like it's meant to strip html tags from input.

I think you're better off using [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: HTML Purifier doesn't strip tags: it outputs valid markup, subject to whichever restrictions you supply.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in UTF-8 mode, as HTML Purifier does by default, there's no need to escape character entities. If you tell HTML Purifier that you're working in ASCII mode, it will do so for you.